# create creates empty objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, markdown

I am trying to  render markdown in :body before saving to database . here 's my create method

```
def create

@post=current_user.posts.create(:title => params[:title],:body => markdown(params[:body])    
redirect_to(post_path(@post))
end
```

and here is my render markdown method

```
def markdown(text)
options = {
  filter_html:     true,
  hard_wrap:       true,
  link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" },
  space_after_headers: true,
  fenced_code_blocks: true
}

extensions = {
  autolink:           true,
  superscript:        true,
  disable_indented_code_blocks: true
}

renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)

markdown.render(text).html_safe
end
```

but when I enter data and submit empty objects are genearated.

```
irb(main):001:0> Post.last
Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY 
"posts"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Post id: 7, title: nil, body: nil, created_at: "2017-04-26 
11:23:12", updated_at: "2017-04-26 11:23:12", user_id: 1>
```

my form :-

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
 =f.input :title 
 =f.input :body
 =f.button :submit
```

Comment: Are you sure `params[:title]` and `params[:body]` is returning any content? How is your form coded?

Comment: updated with my form

Comment: First you might need to add a presence validation on `body` in `Post` model if you don't want posts to be created with blank body content.

Comment: Same for the `title`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I made those changes and modified post.rb now the markdown function throws an error "wrong argument type nil (expected String)" somehow params hash is not returning a string

Comment: Can you print the output of `params` in the first line on `create` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
@post=current_user.posts.create(:title => params[:post][:title],:body => markdown(params[:post][:body])
```

Also you probably would like to check [Rails StrongParam](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) for enhanced security.